# How many committees of $7$ people can be formed in a class of $14$ boys and $10$ girls if the committee is to contain at least $4$ boys?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a class of $14$ boys and $10$ girls, a committee of $7$ is to be formed. How many committees are possible.

(a) if anybody can serve in the committee?

(b) if the committee is to have exactly $4$ boys?

(c) if the committee is to contain at least $4$ boys?

Comment: (a) $\binom{24}{7}$ (b) $\binom{14}{4}\binom{10}{3}$ (c) $\binom{14}{4}\binom{10}{3} + \binom{14}{5}\binom{10}{2} + \binom{14}{6}\binom{10}{1} + \binom{14}{7}\binom{10}{0}$. That's it, I hope?

Comment: Thank you for copy-pasting your homework assignment into our service. Please stand by while our neural-network algorithm is auto-generating an answer to your question. One of our representatives will be with you shortly. On the meanwhile, please prepare your 16-digit credit card number, including your full name, expiration date and those 3 digits on the back of the card which for some reason are not on the front with the rest of them. Since this is a social-network web service, the cost will be 1 bitcoin per user. Thanks again for choosing to work with us.

Comment: its so simple question

Answer (score 1):

Case 1-

C(24,7)

= $\frac{24!}{7!\times17!}$

Case 2-

C(14,4) $\times$ C(10,3)

= $\frac{14!}{4!\times10!} \times \frac{14!}{4!\times10!}$

Case 3-

At least 4 boys, so may be 5 or 6 or 7.

C(14,4) $\times$ C(10,3) + C(14,5) $\times$ C(10,2) + C(14,6) $\times$ C(10,1) + C(14,4)

= $\frac{14!}{4!\times10!} \times \frac{10!}{3!\times7!} + \frac{14!}{5!\times9!} \times \frac{10!}{2!\times8!} + \frac{14!}{6!\times8!} \times \frac{10!}{1!\times9!} + \frac{14!}{7!\times7!}$

Answer (score 1):

(a) $24\choose 7$

(b)select four boys and three girls

$14\choose 4$$ 10\choose 3$

(c) case 4 boys

$14\choose 4$$ 10\choose 3$

case 5 boys

$14\choose 5 $$10\choose 2$

case 6 boys

$14\choose 6 $$10\choose 1$

case 7 boys

$14\choose 7$

sum up all the cases

$14\choose 4$$ 10\choose 3$$ +$$14\choose 5$$ 10\choose 2$$ +$$14\choose 6$$ 10\choose 1$$ +$$14\choose 7$